# OpenMP - Calling external functions in a parallel for loop

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have very little experience using OpenMP. I'm trying to run a for loop in parallel which calls another external function. I'm compiling the program with MinGW so unfortunately I don't get any sort of error which indicates what I'm doing wrong, the program simply doesn't run when I attempt to add a parallel for outside my loop. findCombinations() is a fairly large function which calls another function itself. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a parallel for loop in this scenario? and if so, is there anything I'm doing blatantly wrong?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int j = 0; j < n[i].count; j++) { 
    int length = 0;
    while(n[i].neighbourhoods[j][length].index != -1) length++;
    bool used[length];
    memset(used, false, sizeof(used));
    findCombinations(&b, n[i].neighbourhoods[j], length, 0, 0, used, n[i].col);
    free(n[i].neighbourhoods[j]);
}
```

Here is findCombinations()

```
int findCombinations(struct blocks *b, struct element neighbourhood[], int neighbourhoodSize, int start, int currLen, bool used[], int col) {    
    if (currLen == blocksize) {
        b->blocks[b->count].elements = malloc((blocksize+1) * sizeof(struct element)); 
        b->blocks[b->count].col = col;
        int blockCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighbourhoodSize; i++) {
            if (used[i] == true) {
                b->blocks[b->count].elements[blockCount++] = neighbourhood[i];
            }
        }
        b->blocks[b->count].elements[blocksize] = neighbourhood[neighbourhoodSize]; //ensures the last item is -1
        b->blocks[b->count].signature = getSignature(b->blocks[b->count].elements);
        return 1;
    }
    if (start == neighbourhoodSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    int new = 0;

    used[start] = true;
    b->count += findCombinations(b, neighbourhood, neighbourhoodSize, start + 1, currLen + 1, used, col);

    used[start] = false;
    b->count += findCombinations(b, neighbourhood, neighbourhoodSize, start + 1, currLen, used, col);

    return new;
}
```

I think the issue might be that findCombinations() modifies the pointer I send to it, *b, possibly causing a race condition. My problem is I'm not sure how to work around it.

Comment: Please provide a complete example so that we can better help you. First thought though- make sure you enable OpenMP support in your compiler. For example, if you use GCC on Linux then you need to include `-fopenmp` in the compile string.

Comment: Sorry - added the function called by it now. I'm using windows and I've installed MinGW to compile with gcc, just compiling via command line with -fopenmp

Comment: Of course you have a problem with all your threads working on the same pointer `b`. It becomes even worse while realizing that `findCombinations()` is a recursive function. You should probably be able to fix that by using some `critical` sections here and there, but I'm doubtful the final speed-up would be worth it. If you need performance, you'd probably better off seriously rethinking your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using functions from other libraries is perfectly valid inside OpenMP parallel regions in your providing those libraries provide thread-safe routines, otherwise you might be subject to data races that you cannot control and, therefore, you can only make one routine call at a time.

If you are not sure whether your program is thread safe, you can try to use some tools like Valgrind's [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) or GCC/LLVM's [thread sanitizer](https://lwn.net/Articles/598486/).